# React state unable to update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am passing in the state - IsLoggedIn from the App component to the Header component. But, whenever the onClick event triggers, the IsLoggedIn should change it's state. But, this does not seem to be happening. I don't know why this keeps on happening? Does the App component re render itself with the isLoggedIn being false everytime?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Header from './Header';
import DashBoard from './Dashboard';
import Home from './Home';

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isLoggedIn: false
        }
    }

    onEventClick = () => {
        if (this.state.isLoggedIn) {
            this.setState({isLoggedIn: false});
        }
        else {
            this.setState({isLoggedIn: true});
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="container">
                    <Header onEventClick={this.onEventClick} LoggedInState={this.state.isLoggedIn}/>
                    <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home}/> 
                    <Route path="/dashboard" exact={true} component={DashBoard}/>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    renderContent() {
        if (this.props.LoggedInState) {
            return (
                <li>
                    <a onClick={this.props.onEventClick} href="/api/logout" style={{borderRadius: '12px'}} className="waves-effect waves-light btn-small green darken-1">
                        Log Out
                    </a>
                </li>
            );
        }
        else {
            return (
                <li>
                    <a href="/auth/spotify" onClick={this.props.onEventClick} style={{borderRadius: '12px'}} className="waves-effect waves-light btn green darken-1">
                        Log in with Spotify
                    </a>
                </li>
            );
        }
    }
    

    render() {
        return (
            <nav>
                <div className="nav-wrapper blue-grey darken-4" style={{paddingLeft: '4px'}}>
                    <Link to={this.props.LoggedInState ? '/dashboard' : '/'} className="brand-logo">TuneIn</Link>
                    <ul className="right">
                        {this.renderContent()}
                    </ul>
                </div>
          </nav>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: Can you please post the code as text instead? Thanks!

Comment: Done! Can you please check now. Thank you!

Comment: I've had this happen before.  An easy check would just be to log the value of ```isLoggedIn``` inside your if else statements to see when it gets toggled.  If you notice that it triggers twice within that function, then you know that's what you need to fix.  If that is the case I would get rid of the if else and change it to: ```this.setState({isLoggedIn: !this.state.isLoggedIn})```

Comment: I tried doing that. It toggles twice and then gets set to the default state. Don't know why this is happening. I tried doing what you said too, but it doesn't work @Michael

Comment: <a> tag is rendering the page immediately so you need to prevent it. onClick={(e)=>this.props.onEventClick(e)}   and in onEventClick function used e.preventDefault()

Comment: but, doing that doesn't allow all the other components to render automatically. So, that is a problem

Comment: Is there any other way to prevent the re rendering? Because my state changes for a split second, and then changes back to what it was initially

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your state is not updating is that you have an anchor  tag which after clicking on it causes the page to reload to the next page, therefore, your state resets back to the default false. Do this instead.

In your header.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class Header extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
}

renderContent() {
if (this.props.LoggedInState) {
  return (
    <li>
      <Link
        to="/api/logout"
        onClick={this.props.onEventClick}
        style={{ borderRadius: "12px" }}
        className="waves-effect waves-light btn-small green darken-1"
      >
        Log Out
      </Link>
    </li>
  );
} else {
  return (
    <li>
      <Link
        to="/auth/spotify"
        onClick={this.props.onEventClick}
        style={{ borderRadius: "12px" }}
        className="waves-effect waves-light btn green darken-1"
      >
        Log in with Spotify
      </Link>
    </li>
   );
 }
}

render() {
return (
  <nav>
    <div
      className="nav-wrapper blue-grey darken-4"
      style={{ paddingLeft: "4px" }}
    >
      <Link
        to={this.props.LoggedInState ? "/dashboard" : "/"}
        className="brand-logo"
      >
        TuneIn
      </Link>
      <ul className="right">{this.renderContent()}</ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
 );
}
}

export default Header;
```

Alternatively, if you want to keep your header.js unchanged, you could use local storage as a check to update your state accordingly. In your app.js you can do this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Header from "./components/Header";
import DashBoard from "./components/Dashboard";
import Home from "./components/Home";

class App extends Component {
constructor() {
super();
this.state = {
  isLoggedIn: localStorage.getItem("isloggedIn") || false,
 };
}

onEventClick = () => {
const isLogged = localStorage.setItem("isloggedIn", true);
if (this.state.isLoggedIn === false) {
  this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
 } else {
  localStorage.removeItem("isloggedIn");
  this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false });
 }
 };

render() {
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div className="container">
      <Header
        onEventClick={this.onEventClick}
        LoggedInState={this.state.isLoggedIn}
      />
      <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />
      <Route path="/dashboard" exact={true} component={DashBoard} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
 );
}
```

}

export default App;

Comment: The problem with this is that when I change it to Link, then my API set up in Node.js for the back end does not redirect after. `app.get('/api/logout', (req, res) => {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    })` @Jonathan

Comment: This redirect does not take place to go back to the Home page ('/')

Comment: @UddhavBhagat I have updated my answer check if this helps you out.